# Mlflow not running on machine

Tags: r, machine-learning, mlflow

Please I am trying to run mlflow code in R after having installed it. However, after loading the library with `library(mlflow)` and I run `mlflow_log_params("foo",42)` I get the error message below printed in my console:

```
Error in rethrow_call(c_processx_exec, command, c(command, args), pty,  : 
  Command 'C:/Users/IFEANYI/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-mlflow-1.19.0/mlflow' not found @win/processx.c:982 (processx_exec)
```

I also get the same error message when I run `mlflow_ui()`. Please was there something I ought to have done during installation failure of which is affecting its functionality? Do I need to install and load the processx library in order for mlflow to run on my Windows10 machine? I really hope I can get advice to help me because I want to use mlflow in my machine learning projects. Thanks in advance of your generous help.

Comment: Please can somebody be so kind as to offer a suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error should disappear when setting `MLFLOW_BIN` system variable (Windows) to mlflow cli executable : "....conda\envs\r-mlflow-1.24.0\Scripts\mlflow.exe".
If it works please mark the problem as resolved.

Unfortunately, you will get next error "`Error in wait_for(function() mlflow_rest("experiments", "list", client = client)`" for which I cannot find the solution

Comment: I have the same error "Error in wait_for(function() mlflow_rest("experiments", "list", client = client)". Maybe You managed to solve it? When I run R and mlflow in a docker container the problem is gone, so it seems to be a problem with the operating system (?)